# Is it just me, or does setting a modal on a dialog after it is created just not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Take this jsFiddle as example: http://jsfiddle.net/mostthingsweb/cfDHm/3/.

Note that I am able to use `d.dialog("option", "title", "Dynamically set title")` to set the title after the dialog has been created. But, using `d.dialog("option", "modal", true)` does not visually work. However, according to the dialog itself, `modal` is set to `true` after the call.

Should I file a bug report, or am I overlooking something?

P.S. (& shameless plug): Your assistance will benefit [dialogWrapper](https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/dialogwrapper/wiki/Home).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to close and re-open the dialog for this to work:

```
d1.dialog("close");
d1.dialog("option", "modal", true);
d1.dialog("open");
```

Updated fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cfDHm/4/

Comment: Good find, that did it. Thanks!